# Python Regular expression: is there a symbol to search for more than one occurence of a pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I know that `*` is 0 or more, and `+` is 1 or more, but what if I wanted to indicate 2 or more (more than 1)?

For example, I have

```
>>> y = 'U0_0, P33, AVG'
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', y)
['U', 'P', 'AVG']
```

But I only want to obtain ones that have 2 or more letters. In this example, `AVG`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
y = 'U0_0, P33, AVG'
print re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]{2,}', y)

                            ^^^
```

`{m,n}
    Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible. For example, a{3,5} will match from 3 to 5 'a' characters. Omitting m specifies a lower bound of zero, and omitting n specifies an infinite upper bound. As an example, a{4,}b will match aaaab or a thousand 'a' characters followed by a b, but not aaab. The comma may not be omitted or the modifier would be confused with the previously described form.`

Comment: just curious, is there an optional entry after the comma in the brackets? otherwise, what's the purpose of the comma?

Comment: @AlanH yes you can limit match by saying a number after `,`.like `{2,3}` will match more than 1 and less than 4

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following in place of `*` or `+`:

```
{2,}     (two or more)
```

Additionally, If you want to match from two to five you could do this way:

```
{2,5}    (two to five example)
```

Comment: Another way, just use `re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+', y)` :)

Comment: Yes.. `2 = 1 + 1` obviously :)